# why a constexpr expression of literal class type with a pointer subobject can't be a non-type template argument

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

After looking at [the](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1837r0.html) post about non-type template argument,I have a confusion for an example in that post,I cite the example here:

```cpp
struct VariableLengthString {
   const char *data_ = nullptr;
   constexpr VariableLengthString(const char *p) : data_(p) {}
   auto operator<=>(const VariableLengthString&) const = default;
};

template<VariableLengthString S>
int bar() {
   static int i = 0;
   return ++i;
}

int main() {
   int x = bar<"hello">(); // ERROR
}
```

The post says "the relevant wording is [temp.arg.nontype]/2",So I took a look at that rule,It constrains what can be a non-type template argument.

> A template-argument for a non-type template-parameter shall be **a converted constant expression** of the type of the template-parameter.

So,I took a look at `converted constant expression`,Its definitions are here:

> A converted constant expression of type T is an expression, implicitly converted to type T, where the converted expression is **a constant expression** and the implicit conversion sequence contains only...

What is a constant expression?These rules are here:

> An expression e is a core constant expression unless the evaluation of e, following the rules of the abstract machine, would evaluate one of the following expressions:
>
> > (2.2)  an invocation of a function other than **a constexpr constructor for a literal class**, a constexpr function, or an implicit invocation of a trivial destructor.

So,Is the class type `VariableLengthString` a literal class?Yes,it is.what rules can prove that are here:

> A type is a literal type if it is:
>   1. possibly cv-qualified void; or
>   2. a scalar type; or
>   3. a reference type; or
>   4. an array of literal type; or
>   a possibly cv-qualified class type that has all of the following properties:
>
> > 1. it has a trivial destructor,
> > 2. it is either a closure type, an aggregate type, or has at least one constexpr constructor or constructor template (possibly inherited from a base class) that is not a copy or move constructor,
> > 3. if it is not a union, all of its non-static data members and base classes are of non-volatile literal types.

The key point is that,Are these types of sub-objects of ojbects of type `VariableLengthString` all literal types? Does the class `VariableLengthString` have at least one constexpr constructor?Yes they are.Because of these rules:

> Arithmetic types, enumeration types, **pointer types**, pointer to member types ([basic.compound]), std​::​nullptr_­t, and cv-qualified versions of these types are collectively called **scalar types**.

So,the sub-object `data_`,it's of type pointer.hence,it's scalar type,also a literal type.The bullet 3 is satisfied.Does `constexpr VariableLengthString(const char *p)` a constexpr constructor?Yes,it is,Because of these rules:

> The definition of a constexpr constructor shall satisfy the following requirements:
>
> > 1. the class shall not have any virtual base classes;
> > 2. each of the parameter types shall be a literal type;
> > 3. every non-variant non-static data member and base class subobject shall be initialized

For `constexpr VariableLengthString(const char *p)`,these three rules are all be satisfied.In summary,the class `VariableLengthString` is a literal type and a constexpr expression of type `VariableLengthString` could be used as a non-type template argument,because it satisfies the requirement of being **a converted constant expression**.why the code above is ill-formed?If I miss something,please help me find out them.

Comment: "and the implicit conversion sequence contains only" The rest of that sentence sounded kind of important, since you are in fact using an implicit conversion sequence.

Comment: @NicolBolas It possible a key point,However the same things also happen on example **2** in that post,why that example is well-formed?If **and the implicit conversion sequence contains only** would be a key point.

Comment: @NicolBolas  In other words,In that example ,from "char const(&)[6]" to "char const*" that is the parameter's type of FixedLengthString 's constructor,It's a "Array-to-pointer" conversion and from "char const*" to FixedLengthString,It's a user-defined conversion.So,two conversions are here.However that example is well-formed.

Comment: That paper is out of date: the problems it describes were fixed by [P1907R1](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2019/p1907r1.html) (although that has very little discussion).

Comment: There is a very simple work around: https://godbolt.org/z/RTpfHu

Comment: @DavisHerring You are right,but I think another answers can also be found in the old standard,that is [const.expr/5.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.const#5.3),so the subobject "data_" need to satisfy  above rules,it violates [const.expr/5.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.const#5.2),so it's not a constant expression.

Comment: @jackX: /5.2 isn’t violated: a string literal [has static storage duration](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/lex.string#8) (and so do its elements).  It *is* a constant expression, just not one that’s usable as a template argument (in either language version).

Comment: @DavisHerring Indeed,you are right,thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The code is ill-formed because [the standard says so](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.arg.nontype#3):

> For a non-type template-parameter of reference or pointer type, or **for each non-static data member of reference or pointer type in a non-type template-parameter of class type or subobject thereof,** the reference or pointer value shall not refer to or be the address of (respectively):
>
> ...
>
> - a string literal

Emphasis added. C++17 and before would not allow you to use a pointer (or reference) to a literal as an NTTP. C++20 therefore doesn't allow you to *smuggle* a pointer (or reference) to a literal through a class member of an NTTP.

Comment: I can't find the sentence "or for each non-static data member of reference or pointer type in a non-type template-parameter of class type or subobject thereof",where are them in the standard?

Comment: @jackX: I copied that from the wrong standard. User-defined NTTPs are not part of C++17; they're part of C++20.

Comment: Hi,NicolBolas,I think the answers are here [expr.const/5.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.const#5.3),the template argument is used as a prvalue,so 5.3 is required,that sub-object 'data_' does not satisfy the bullet 5.2,so,it's not a constant expression but a core constant expression

Comment: @jackX: That has nothing to do with what the proposal was discussing. There's nothing about the expression that prevents it from being a constant expression; it's all about being an NTTP. That's why it's not legal.