# Match template with Class Template Deduction Placeholder param

Tags: c++, c++20, type-deduction

Trying to use string literals as non-type template parameters in GCC 10.1. Have the following code:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

template<std::size_t n> struct fixed_string {
  constexpr fixed_string(char const (&s)[n]) {
    std::copy_n(s, n, this->el);
  }
  constexpr fixed_string(fixed_string<n> const& s) {
    std::copy_n(s.el, n, this->el);
  }
  constexpr bool operator==(fixed_string const&) const = default;
  constexpr auto operator<=>(fixed_string const&) const = default;
  char el[n];
};
template<std::size_t n> fixed_string(char const(&)[n])->fixed_string<n>;

template<fixed_string str>
class Base {
public:
  Base() {
    std::cout << str.el << std::endl;
  }
};

template<fixed_string str>
class Derived : public Base<str> {
};


int main(void) {
  Derived<"Hello World"> x;
}
```

`Base` on it's own works fine, trying to figure out how to pass string literals up the class hierarchy. I thought a copy constructor would work, and GCC spits out this lovely error message and laughs at my attempt:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘fixed_string(fixed_string<...auto...>)’
note: candidate: ‘template<long unsigned int n> fixed_string(const fixed_string<n>&)-> fixed_string<n>’
constexpr fixed_string(fixed_string<n> const& s) {
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~
note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
note:   mismatched types ‘const fixed_string<n>’ and ‘fixed_string<...auto...>’
```

Cool. So `<...auto...>` is [GCC speak](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/6e6e3f144a33ae504149dc992453b4f6dea12fdb/gcc/cp/error.c#L558-L565) for a ["Class Template Deduction Placeholder"](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/6e6e3f144a33ae504149dc992453b4f6dea12fdb/gcc/cp/pt.c#L27726-L27732) and I don't know how to threaten the compiler to match that with my function calls. Does anyone know how to coerce GCC here? Or alternatively how to propagate string literals through a class hierarchy?

Fun fact, passing `str.el` to the `Base` template [crashes GCC](https://godbolt.org/z/hzsa5E).

Comment: I asked something similar yesterday :-) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62853609/understanding-user-defined-string-literals-addition-for-c20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is certainly a gcc bug. I have experienced it and found this workaround:

```
template<std::size_t n> struct fixed_string {
    consteval fixed_string(char const (&s)[n]) {
        std::copy_n(s, n, this->el);
    }
    consteval fixed_string(const fixed_string<n>& s) = default;
    consteval bool operator==(fixed_string const&) const = default;
    consteval auto operator<=>(fixed_string const&) const = default;
    char el[n];
    static const std::size_t size = n;
};
template<std::size_t n> fixed_string(char const(&)[n])->fixed_string<n>;

template<std::size_t n, fixed_string<n> str>
class BaseImpl {
    public:
        BaseImpl() {
            std::cout << str.el << std::endl;
        }
};

template <fixed_string s>
using Base = BaseImpl<s.size, s>;

template<std::size_t n, fixed_string<n> str>
class DerivedImpl : public BaseImpl<n, str> {
};

template <fixed_string s>
using Derived = DerivedImpl<s.size, s>;

int main(void) {
    Derived<"Hello World"> x;
}
```

Or alternatively

```
template<fixed_string str>
class Base {
    public:
        Base() {
            std::cout << str.el << std::endl;
        }
};

template <std::size_t n, fixed_string<n> s>
using BaseWrapper = Base<s>;

template<fixed_string str>
class Derived : public BaseWrapper<str.size, str> {
};
```

The general idea is to avoid using a deduced parameter to deduce another one.

Comment: I played around with similar solutions too, I was hoping I was missing something. Thanks!