# How to detect const char* format errors at C++ compile time?

Tags: c++, templates, constexpr, compile-time

I'm trying to write a function "my_func()" that counts the number of characters "a" in a string at compile time, which makes the code fail to compile when the count of "a" is wrong.

I was inspired by the function `std::format()` in the C++ standard library, which checks the number of `{}` in the format string.

The compiler I use is msvc, C++20.

My code below won't compile because I don't know how to implement functionality like this. So how can I fix function `my_func()`?

```cpp
template <size_t Size>
auto my_func(const char(&str)[Size]) -> void {
    // dosomething...

    constexpr size_t count = 0;
    const char* c = str;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < Size; ++i) {
        if (*c == 'a') {
            count++; // const values cannot be modified
        }
        c++;
    }

    // If the variable `count ` is not set to constexpr, an error will be reported here.
    static_assert(count == 2);

    // dosomething...
}

auto main() -> int {
    my_func("abc abc"); // is error
}
```

**Next**

Thanks to @ecatmur for the answer, but I don't know how to get the value of str when str is converted to `counting_string`.

I tried passing the constructor's template parameters to the class, but this prevented me from finding the matching overloaded function when calling the `prepare` function.

```cpp
template <char Char, size_t Count, size_t Size>
struct counting_string {
    std::array<char, Size> m_chars;

    // NOLINTNEXTLINE(google-explicit-constructor)
    consteval explicit(false) counting_string(char const (&str)[Size]) {
        size_t count = 0;
        const char* c = str;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < Size; ++i) {
            if (*c == Char) {
                count++;
            }
            c++;
        }
        if (count != Count) {
            throw "invalid str";
        }
    }
};

template <size_t Size, class... Args>
auto prepare(const counting_string<'?', sizeof...(Args), Size> sql, Args... args) -> void {
// use sql as: sql.m_chars.data();
}

auto main() -> int {
    // call function error
    // prepare("insert into test (name, age) values (?, ?)", 1, 2);
}
```

The code below is the end result I hope to achieve.
Without extra overhead (compile-time checking), check the number of placeholders in SQL statements to avoid mistakes.

```cpp
template <char Char, size_t Count>
struct constexpr_counting_string {
    template <size_t Size>
    // NOLINTNEXTLINE(google-explicit-constructor)
    consteval explicit(false) constexpr_counting_string(char const (&str)[Size]) {
        size_t count = 0;
        const char* c = str;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < Size; ++i) {
            if (*c == Char) {
                count++;
            }
            c++;
        }
        if (count != Count) {
            throw "invalid str";
        }
    }
};

// prepare and bind
template <typename... Args>
auto prepare(statement_t& stmt, constexpr_counting_string<'?', sizeof...(Args)> sql, Args... args) noexcept -> code_t {
    // prepare
    code_t error = helper_prepare(stmt, sql);

    // bind
    auto do_bind = [](statement_t& stmt, size_t n, auto arg, code_t& error) noexcept {
        if (error != code_t::ok) {
            return;
        }

        using arg_type = decltype(arg);

        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<arg_type, uint64_t>) {
            error = stmt.bind(n, arg);
        }
        else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<arg_type, int64_t>) {
            error = stmt.bind(n, arg);
        }
        else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<arg_type, int>) {
            error = stmt.bind(n, arg);
        }
        else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<arg_type, const char*>) {
            error = stmt.bind(n, arg);
        }
        else {
            static_assert(std::is_same_v<arg_type, uint64_t>, "args error");
        }
    };

    size_t index = 0;
    (do_bind(stmt, index++, args, error), ...);
    return error;
}

auto main() -> int {
    prepare("insert into test (name, age) values (?, ?)", 1, 2);
}
```

Comment: Just curious, why are you using a `const char*` pointer at compile-time to iterate `str` instead of just using `str[i]`?

Comment: @Remy Lebeau There's no particular reason for this. I think they are completely equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is that `std::format` checks in the `consteval` constructor of `std::format_string` that the format-string argument is well-formed and appropriate for the `std::format` arguments that follow.

This means that you need to invert your logic; the simplest way would be to write a `counting_string` type whose `consteval` constructor accepts only string literals containing 2 `'a'`s:

```cpp
struct counting_string {
    template<unsigned Size>
    consteval explicit(false) counting_string(char const (&str)[Size]) {
        unsigned count = 0;
        const char* c = str;
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < Size; ++i) {
            if (*c == 'a') {
                count++; // const values cannot be modified
            }
            c++;
        }
        if (count != 2) throw "invalid str";
    }
};
auto my_func(counting_string str) -> void {
    ; // if we get here we know `str` contains 2 'a's
}
```

[Example](https://godbolt.org/z/jYc4f6qj4).

For style points, you might want to [make `counting_string` a class template](https://godbolt.org/z/c3Pq9ce4e).

For the **follow up question**, the problem is that we can't use `std::string` in the `consteval` constructor since it would need to allocate memory, and (currently) [memory allocations can't be passed from compile time to run time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72415239/how-do-i-store-the-compile-time-dynamically-allocated-memory-so-that-it-can-be-u). Also, we can't use a static string (or, e.g., `std::array<char, Size>`) since class template argument deduction (CTAD) isn't smart enough to infer a `Size` class template parameter from a function template function argument. (Annoyingly, CTAD *is* smart enough to do so [from a non-type function template *template* argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62853609/understanding-user-defined-string-literals-addition-for-c20) - but that doesn't help here.)

So, the only thing to do is to store a *pointer* (or, e.g., a `std::string_view`) to the string literal in the `counting_string`, and hope that the argument that the user passed in has a long enough lifetime (if it is indeed a string literal, it'll be fine - the only problem would be if it was the `char` array data member of a static string or `std::array<char>`.) Indeed, [this is how `std::format_string` works](https://eel.is/c++draft/format.fmt.string), so it has the same potential problem. [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/PMs1Yrdx3):

```cpp
#include <string_view>
struct counting_string {
    template<unsigned Size>
    consteval explicit(false) counting_string(char const (&str)[Size]) : sv(str, Size) {
        unsigned count = 0;
        for (char const c : sv)
            if (c == 'a')
                count++; // const values cannot be modified
        if (count != 2) throw "invalid str";
    }
    std::string_view sv;
};
```

Comment: How can I get the data of the string after the parameter type is converted to `counting_string`?

Comment: @qingl good question. We can't use std::string, since that allocates memory which can't be propagated from compile time to runtime, so we need to use std::string_view (and hope that the caller provided an actual string literal with the correct lifetime): https://godbolt.org/z/8qTfjaYbY

Answer (score 1):

You could add a `constexpr` checker:

```cpp
#include <cstddef> // size_t
#include <utility> // index_sequence's

template <std::size_t Size>
constexpr std::size_t number_of_as(const char (&str)[Size]) { 
    return [&]<std::size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
        return (... + (str[Is] == 'a')); // fold expression 
    }(std::make_index_sequence<Size>());
}
```

```cpp
int main() {
    static_assert(number_of_as("abc abc") == 2); // pass
}
```