# How do I parameterize a consteval lambda?

Tags: c++, c++20

### Background

I am using a NTTP (non-type template parameter) lambda to store a `string_view` into a type at compile time:

```
template<auto getStrLambda>
struct MyType {
    static constexpr std::string_view myString{getStrLambda()};
};

int main() {
    using TypeWithString = MyType<[]{return "Hello world";}>;
    return 0;
}
```

This works, and achieves my main intention.

### Question

My question now is, to make this easier to use, **how can I write a wrapper function to create the lambda for me**?

I'm thinking something like:

```
// This helper function generates the lambda, rather than writing the lambda inline
consteval auto str(auto&& s) {
    return [s]() consteval {
        return s;
    };
};

template<auto getStrLambda>
struct MyType {
    static constexpr std::string_view myString{getStrLambda()};
};

int main() {
    using TypeWithString = MyType<str("Hello world")>;
    return 0;
}
```

The above [fails on clang](https://godbolt.org/z/js4v9b5Ks) since the lambda isn't structural, since it needs to capture the string:

```
error: type '(lambda at <source>:4:12)' of non-type template parameter is not a structural type
    using TypeWithString = MyType<str("Hello world")>;
                                  ^
note: '(lambda at <source>:4:12)' is not a structural type because it has a non-static data member that is not public
    return [s]() consteval {
            ^
```

Given that it's possible for a lambda to use a variable without capturing it if the variable is initialized as a constant expression ([source](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)), how can I define a function to parameterize this lambda return value at compile time?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing a string literal to a template char array parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68024563/2752075)

Comment: "*I am using a NTTP lambda to store a string_view into a type at compile time*" Why does that "string_view" have to be a view of a string *literal*? That's the core of the problem here: [string literals, or any pointer into such a string, can *never* be an NTTP. Ever.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61839451/734069) Not as a member of a structural type. Nowhere. You are not allowed to smuggle string literals into template substitution. So don't try; just store an array of characters.

Comment: @NicolBolas I'm not trying to pass a string literal, or pointer to string literal as the NTTP, the NTTP is a lambda that returns a string literal. Or are you saying that would also be UB?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat that doesn't actually answer my specific question, but it does provide another way to create a class template that can store a string at compile-time without the need for a consteval lambda. I may just use that, thanks!

Comment: @JamesMart: "*the NTTP is a lambda that returns a string literal.*" You want the lambda to *store* the literal. That means the literal must be a member of the lambda via capture.

Comment: @NicolBolas No, I don't want the lambda to store the literal. I want it to return a literal, which is simple enough if I define the lambda inline. The question is if I can create a consteval function to generate the lambda that similarly *avoids* the capture.

Comment: Are you asking "where exactly does the standard prevent this trick, which by my reading is legal, from working?" or "why won't the C++ language let me do this?"?  These are subtly different questions.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Actually neither. The lambda seems to allow me to construct a static string_view in my type at compile time. I simply can't figure out how to write a function that would generate the lambda at compile-time for me. I've edited the OP to make it smaller & clearer.

Comment: @JamesMart: "*I want it to return a literal*" And where does it get it from? It either comes through a parameter or a capture/member. If it gets it from somewhere else, then every call of the function will get the same value, so if you want different invocations of the function to get different results, then that must be through either a parameter passed at call time or a capture/member.

Comment: @JamesMart: Either way, at the bottom, you are trying to smuggle a string literal through a template argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [CWG2542](https://wg21.link/CWG2542).

Prior to the linked issue's resolution, GCC and Clang are both not actually incorrect in accepting or rejecting the program. The lambda's type simply has a data member of type `char[12]`, which was allowed to be public or private. It seems that Clang treats them as private members.

But now, after CWG2542, capturing lambdas cannot have structural types, so you have to do something else.

The obvious solution is to write out the closure type explicitly ensuring the data member is always public:

```cpp
consteval auto str(auto&& s) {
    static_assert(std::is_array_v<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(s)>>);
    return [&]<std::size_t... I>(std::index_sequence<I...>) {
        struct {
            std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(s)> value;
            consteval std::decay_t<decltype(s)> operator()() const {
                return value;
            }
        } functor{{std::forward<decltype(s)>(s)[I]...}};
        return functor;
    }(std::make_index_sequence<std::extent_v<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(s)>>>{});
}
```

The great thing about this is that it will have the same type for strings of the same length, so `MyType<str("xyz")>` in one translation unit will mangle to the same name as `MyType<str("xyz")>` in another, since it stores an array.

Your goal of `str("string literal")` being a function call and return something "without any capture" is impossible, since the function argument `auto&& s` is not usable in a constant expression. In particular, you can't convert it to a pointer nor can you access any of its items.

You can also have `str` be a type and skip the step of a function:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct str;

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
struct str<T[N]> {
    T value[N];

    constexpr str(const str&) = default;
    consteval str(const T(& v)[N]) : str(std::make_index_sequence<N>{}, v) {}

    consteval auto operator()() const {
        return value;
    }
private:
    template<std::size_t... I>
    consteval str(std::index_sequence<I...>, const T(& v)[N]) : value{ v[I]... } {}
};

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
str(const T(&)[N]) -> str<T[N]>;
```

Where `str("string literal")` is now a structural type holding an array.

Comment: Won't the reference-to-array decay into a pointer-to-first-element when captured by the lambda?  (not in your code; in the OP's code)

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont From https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda#capture-15: "For array members, the array elements are direct-initialized in increasing subscript order." (lambdas have array members if they capture arrays). If they had `[s=s]` then it would decay

Comment: > The lambda's type simply has a data member of type `char[12]`

Why? Why wouldn't the lambda type define `inline const char * operator()() const { return "Hello world"; }`?

Comment: The `index_sequence` part can be removed, the chars can be copied in a simple loop.

Comment: @JamesMart The lambda inside your `str(auto&& s)` function which captures `s` does. The `[]{return "Hello world";}` lambda doesn't, but as I've explained, once you've passed `s` as a function argument it is no longer a constant expression so must be captured.

Comment: @Artyer Ah, nice -- I had presumed it would decay like a function argument does.

Comment: It is too bad we can't use stuff like https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/make_from_tuple to construct an array from an array.